# Move an object to another PDF layer in iTextSharp or PDFSharp

Tags: pdf, itext, layer, pdfsharp

I would like to be able to read in a PDF, and iterate through each of the objects (paths, text object etc). If it meets some criteria, then change the PDF layer that it is on. Is this possible with either iTextSharp or PDFSharp? I can't find much documentation on layers in either.

Comment: What do you mean by *layers*? Do you mean optional content groups (which can be made visible or invisible as a whole)? Or do you have some foreground-background-style layering on your mind? In PDF you generally don't have fixed layers like that; object A simply is 'above' object B if A is drawn after B. Or do you have some other layering concept on your mind?

Comment: Keep in mind that what Adobe Acrobat calls "Layers" are actually Optional Content Groups; just to confuse things more :) So describing the actual problem or use case you are trying to solve / implement would be a good idea.